# Derived Types with Kind Parameter

Tags: gfortran, derived-types, type-kinds

In gfortran I can specify the kind of a variable, for example

```
Real (Real32) :: r
```

I want to create a vector derived type. Is it possible to code it in a way that one can use a similar approach as follows.

```
Vector (Real32) :: v
```

Comment: In Fortran one can parameterize derived types, but as far as I know gfortran doesn't yet support this F2003 feature.

Comment: Parameterize derived types gives the possibility to have the kind parameter specified in the declaration of the member types. This does mean that integers and reals must exist seperately. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it's only the kind- and length-type parameters that can be "parameterized", not the (intrinsic) types themselves.  That is, you'd need different parameterized derived types to contain each different (combination of) types.  Much as with `int(int32)` and `real(real32)`.